# How do I get the name of the branch which the active release is based on?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a release pipeline per component that deploys a build to multiple environments, where each environment is represented as a stage:

[image: Our release pipeline]

I'm wondering if there's an API I can use to get the branch name of the active release (i.e. the field highlighted in yellow).

Note that I'm expecting to get a potentially different branch name for each environment (stage) as we don't always deploy to all environments, so often you end up with DEV correlating to Release-002, SIT to Release-001, TEST to Release-010, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the [Azure DevOps CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines/build?view=azure-cli-latest#az-pipelines-build-list) You can easily interrogate several aspects of you DevOps configuration. I've just done a `Top 1` but you can do advanced queries on the data, see the docs.

[image]

Here's the command i ran;

```
az pipelines build list --organization https://dev.azure.com/gordonbyers --project ham --top 1 --query "[].{branch: sourceBranch, startTime: startTime, status: status, buildNum:buildNumber}"
```

---

If you don't want to take a dependency on the DevOps CLI then you can achieve exactly the same results by leveraging the [DevOps API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) directly, but you'll need to do more parsing of the response.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear - I need to call this from vanilla javascript so I'm looking for a url rather than an az command

Comment: you can use the DevOps API then, but will need to perform more work parsing the response.